# How can I split a UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I would like to achieve a UITableViewCell to look like this image (following/tweets/etc):

[alt text http://etch-reviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/tweetie-2-profile-screen.jpg](http://etch-reviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/tweetie-2-profile-screen.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CoreGraphics to draw the text and divide lines manually in a `UITableViewCell` subclass

<sup>(this is all Twitter for iPhone does)</sup>

Comment: I'm not familiar with CoreGraphics. Can you show me an example?

Comment: Override `drawRect:`. Call `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` to get the current graphics context. Call `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor` to set the stroke color. Use `CGContextMoveToPoint` and `CGContextAddLineToPoint` to set a path. Use `CGContextStrokePath` to stroke the path.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be to just add 5 subviews to the contentview of the cell in cellforrow, being 4 uitextfields and 1 uiview (the horizontal line). However, this will only be suitable for a tableview with a small number of rows as above as scrolling may suffer for long tables unless rpetrich's drawrect solution is adopted.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use such approach (using CoreGraphics) and then you tap the cell? Will it be colored totally in blue or just the slice you are touching?

Because that's the problem, and that's not even a button.